# Simple XAML viewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewer, xamlwriter

I need to write XAML of a WPF control to string. I used XamlWriter.Save(). It works good. Also I need to format, indent and show the string in a editor (read only) like VS Xaml code view. I dont know how to do this.

Please share your valuable ideas.

Comment: Do you need to write this from scratch or are you willing/allowed to use 3rd party controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [save to a XmlWriter instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590446.aspx), create a XmlWriter, create a [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) instance and set the `Indent` property to true and set this on your XmlWriter. That way you should have the indentation.

Now for a control to display it, you could use the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) in wpf, or look for a custom control around the web.

Comment: When I do this I get this strange namespace definition in the output: `<UserControl  xmlns="clr-namespace:WpfControls1;assembly=WpfControls1" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">`. 

But the original xaml file had the following namespace declarations:


`<UserControl x:Class="WpfControls2.UserControlA" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`